# UIViewController as rootViewController of UINavigationController causes root views buttons to move

Tags: swift4

When I do this in AppDelegate:

```
window?.rootViewController = {

        let mainController = MenuViewController()

        return mainController
    }()
```

I get this:

[image]

But when I do this in AppDelegate:

```
window?.rootViewController = {
    let mainController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: MenuViewController())

    return mainController
}()
```

I get this:

[image]

Why and how do I fix? Please specify which information if more information is needed.

Here is the MenuView code that lays out the buttons manually and also sets up the properties of the buttons:

```
class MenuView: UIView {

    //title
    let titleLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Survive The Attackers!!"
        label.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        return label
    }()

    //set up buttons
    let newGameButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.setTitle("New Game", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        button.layer.borderWidth = 2.0;
        button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor

        return button
    }()
    let resumeButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.setTitle("Resume Game", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        button.layer.borderWidth = 2.0;
        button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor

        return button
    }()

    let highScoresButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.setTitle("High Scores", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        button.layer.borderWidth = 2.0;
        button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor

        return button
    }()

    //add subviews and initialize the view
    override init(frame: CGRect){
        super.init(frame: frame)

        self.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "background1.png")!)
        addSubview(titleLabel)
        addSubview(newGameButton)
        addSubview(resumeButton)
        addSubview(highScoresButton)
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("It's Apple. What did you expect?")
    }

    //manually layout the main menu
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        var cursor: CGPoint = .zero
        let buttonHeight = CGFloat(40.0);
        let buttonWidth = CGFloat(160.0);
        let labelWidth = buttonWidth + 20;
        let spacing = bounds.height/4
        let titleY = 2/3 * spacing

        cursor.y = titleY
        cursor.x = bounds.width/2 - labelWidth/2

        titleLabel.frame = CGRect(x: cursor.x, y: cursor.y, width: labelWidth, height: buttonHeight)

        cursor.y = spacing
        cursor.x = bounds.width/2 - buttonWidth/2

        newGameButton.frame = CGRect(x: cursor.x, y: cursor.y, width: buttonWidth, height: buttonHeight)

        cursor.y += spacing

        resumeButton.frame = CGRect(x: cursor.x, y: cursor.y, width: buttonWidth, height: buttonHeight)

        cursor.y += spacing

        highScoresButton.frame = CGRect(x: cursor.x, y: cursor.y, width: buttonWidth, height: buttonHeight)
    }
```

The buttons are laid out manually in layoutSubviews

Here is my MenuView controller code:

```
class MenuViewController: UIViewController {

    var delegateID: String = UUIDVendor.vendUUID()

    private var menuView: MenuView {
        return view as! MenuView
    }

    init(){
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        //edgesForExtendedLayout = .init(rawValue: 0)
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder){
        fatalError()
    }

    //loads the view in and sizes it correctly
    override func loadView() {
        view = MenuView()
        //extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = false
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        menuView.newGameButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MenuViewController.newGameButtonTapped(button:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        menuView.resumeButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MenuViewController.resumeGameButtonTapped(button:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        menuView.highScoresButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MenuViewController.highScoreButtonTapped(button:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        menuView.setNeedsLayout()
    }

    //fuction that handles the event when the newGameButton is tapped
    @objc func newGameButtonTapped(button: UIButton){
        //reset the data in the model somehow

        navigationController?.pushViewController(GameViewController(), animated: true)
    }

    //function that handles the event when the resume game button is tapped
    @objc func resumeGameButtonTapped(button: UIButton){

    }

    //function that handels the event when the high scores button is tapped
    @objc func highScoreButtonTapped(button: UIButton){

    }
```

Comment: How you added those UIButtons/UILabel? Auto layout or storyboard?

Comment: I added them programatically using layoutSubviews(). Code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call super for layoutSubviews

```
private var menuView: MenuView = {
    let vw = MenuView()
    return vw
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()   

    view = MenuView()       //Add here

    //Your code
}
```

And remove loadView() from MenuViewController

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I added it but nothing happened. I'll post my MenuViewController as well

Comment: Why are you create MenuView? You can add label & buttons in MenuViewController directly. init, required init & loadView also not required in UIViewController.

Comment: Thanks I really appreciate it. It is that way cause it worked the first time I did it honestly. We haven't gotten any guidance on most of the architectural details of our assignments.